# Why does the vampire leather hood have a cream colored appearance when worn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The vampire leather hood displays as a black leather hood in the inventory, but is cream colored when equipped.

Cant find anyone complaining about this, I've seen videos of this hood and it's not supposed to look like that. Is it because I'm an Argonian?

It displays correctly on the mannequins.

I don't have any mods installed.

[image: image of the hood when worn]
[image: image of the hood in my inventory]